# Only show tooltip on specific matrix cells

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a Power BI Matrix that uses an icon for conditional formatting. Right now I'm using a custom report page tooltip to show more info. However, my customer only wants the tooltip to be enabled on cells that have the icon. Else, he wants no tooltip at all. How to implement?

[image]

Comment: Can you share a .pbix?